# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'. > !zip.isFile()

Tags: android

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Venho Recebendo esse erro insuportável, eu vinha contornando ele voltando um tempo atras no meu projeto já que eu faço backup do app, ai algumas vezes funcionava, quando não funcionava eu tinha que refazer o backup, e não sei porque funcionava, mais dessa vez não fiz o backup então preciso solucionar esse problema.

ele aconteceu quando botei o zip do Youtube na pasta libs, esse eu consegui contornar, agora voltou o erro quando botei os zip do Appodeal na pasta libs, Agradeço desde já!

**Atualização**
Descobri que `Rebuild` trabalha pra esse erro.

Answer (score 1):

Clique com o botão direito no root do projeto. Ex: `app select >> Show in Explorer` e delete o arquivo `.gradle` e clique na opção clean ou built. Vai funcionar 100%.